# Android automatic sort list of model when new item is added

Tags: android, sorting, time, android-recyclerview

Hi I have and Android app using RecycleView. I have a model class `Topstory` with a variable `time` (data is `long` value). New item will be added to `List` of `Topstory` (topstories) from a JSON response from server. I want to update the recycle View to add new item but sort the items by time (i.e: newest appear first (by time)).

This is my model

```
public class TopStory {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int score;
    private JSONArray kids;
    private long time;
    private String url;

    public TopStory() {
    }

    public TopStory(int id, String title, String author, int point, long time,String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.score = point;
        this.time = time;
        this.url = url;
    }
```

and my response which contain item to add to List of `TopStory` (topstories)

```
private void getTopStoryDetail(RequestQueue requestQueue, String topStoryUrl, final ProgressBar progressBar) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CustomJsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,topStoryUrl,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject respond) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        TopStory topStory = TopStory.fromJson(respond);
                        topStories.add(topStory);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

How to modify the response code so that each time a new item is add. the list `topstories` will be sorted by time and the `recycleView` display item as order (bytime)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think here `topStories` is your list variable. So, you can sort it by using `Collections.sort(topStories);` for sorting the data and after that notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: thanks for your response but how to sort the topstories by specific variable  (time)

Comment: Google Java comparator.

Comment: You can implement comparable interface to the `TopStory` class and return the difference between two objects time.

Comment: hi t thanks, do u you an example how to implement the interface and call the sorting function?

Comment: have you tried with Java comparator.